# python: select string from a line between two delimiter and print with other strings in same line

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string like below:
INPUT:tempstr=

fnameêkumarêlnameêashishêaddressêbangalore, indiaêPIN=888888, nationalityêINDIANêcontactnumber=888337288, emergencynum=888222222

every field suppose to be delimited by ê. but some field are separated by "=" or ", ". 
I need output like below in python.
Output:txt=

fnameêkumarêlnameêashishêaddressêbangalore, indiaêPINê888888ênationalityêINDIANêcontactnumberê888337288êemergencynumê888222222

I am trying replace function to replace "=" and "' ", but it replace value field also in address values:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
  for i, j in dic.iteritems():
  text = text.replace(i, j)
return text
reps={", ":"ê",
  "=":"ê"}

txt = replace_all(tempstr, reps)
print txt
```

Comment: It's unclear. In your string, you keep one of the two comma. Is this normal? Also, can you add some code to show us what you try?

Comment: Try to explain better and put some code of what you have tried. Also describe the goal of this output, because I suspect some bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex allow you to exclude the substitution when `=` or `,` is followed by a keyword contained in the list:
`fname, lname, address, PIN, nationality, contactnumber,emergencynum`, just add all the keywords needed.

```
tempstr=r'fnameêkumarêlnameêashishêaddressêbangalore, indiaêPIN=888888, nationalityêINDIANêcontactnumber=888337288, emergencynum=888222222'
outputstr = re.sub(r'[=,]\s*(?=fname|lname|address|PIN|nationality|contactnumber|emergencynum)', 'ê', tempstr)
print outputstr
```

**Output:**

```
fnameêkumarêlnameêashishêaddressêbangalore, indiaêPIN=888888ênationalityêINDIANêcontactnumber=888337288êemergencynum=888222222
```

**Explanation:**

```
[=,]    : = sign or comma
\s*     : 0 or more spaces
(?=     : start positive lookahead, 
          it makes sure we have one of the following keyword after
    fname
    |
    lname
    |
    address
    |
    PIN
    |
    nationality
    |
    contactnumber
    |
    emergencynum
)               : end lookahead
```

Comment: Thankyou for response, but this is completely hardcoded. In actual scenario there are total around 200 such fields in a single report. and there are total 10 such report having different different filed name.I need something generalize form.

Comment: @KumarAshish: I'm afraid that is not possible. There're no way to distinguish a comma between 2 fields from a comma inside a field.

Answer (score 0):

ftxt=fnameêkumarêlnameêashishêaddressêbangalore, indiaêPIN=888888, nationalityêINDIANêcontactnumber=888337288, emergencynum=888222222'
out=re.sub(r"(?<==)(?P.*?)(?=, )",r"ê\1ê",ftxt)
print out

def replace_all(text, dic):
  for i, j in dic.iteritems():
  text = text.replace(i, j)
return text
reps3={"=ê":"ê","ê, ":"ê"}
fout=replace_all(out,reps3)